# Get variable from javascript array

Tags: javascript

I'm want to get variable "priceWithVatMin" and "priceWithVatMax" from Javascript "array"

```
     <script>
dataLayer = [];
dataLayer.push({'shoptet' : {
    "pageType": "productDetail",
    "product": {
        "id": 2148,
        "name": "iPhone 7 Plus 32GB Black",
        "currency": "CZK",
        "priceWithVatMin": 12899,
        "priceWithVatMax": 13599
    }
```

i want some like write in console this variable e.g -> `console.log(?)`
Thanks lot :-)

Comment: `dataLayer[0].shoptet.product.priceWithVatMin`

Comment: Hit `F12`, go to Console, type `dataLayer` and see what it is.  You can then try array and object access to find the path you need.  This should not require a S.O. question

Comment: That's not a variable, that's an [object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

Answer (score -1):

```
dataLayer.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.shoptet.product.priceWithVatMin)
})
```

Other answers are accessing just the one item. This is if you want to get every item in the array (presuming you add more).